While linking the assembly object file with GCC, relocation error occurs due to errno setting
as a school project I am asked to rewrite the write function in x86-64 assembly. There are some rules in this project. For example, just as write sets errno in case of an error, my write function should set errno in the same way. Also it is forbidden to use gcc's -no-pie option for compilation and linking. In Linux, we have to set the errno variable with the __errno_location function in the errno.h library. So I call this function in my assembly source file and set it according to the required rules. Then I declare it in my main.c source file to use my write function and use it to test it. Then I enter the compile and link operation commands to do the linking process, but I encounter a problem in linking;
/usr/bin/ld: my_write.o: warning: relocation against `__errno_location@@GLIBC_2.2.5' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: my_write.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `__errno_location@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

the compiler tells me to recompile using the -fPIE option. But when I do it again it gives the same error message.
If I compile with the -no-pie option, it compiles this time, but this is also against the rules
Any idea?

below I share the contents of the files and my compilation steps;
my_write.s;
section .text
global my_write
extern __errno_location

my_write:
    mov rax, 1
    syscall
    cmp rax, -1
    je err
    ret

err:
    neg rax                 
    mov rdi, rax
    call __errno_location
    mov [rax], rdi
    mov rax, -1
    ret

main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

extern ssize_t my_write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);

int main(void)
{
    char *str = "Hello";
    my_write(1, str, 5);
}

compilation and linking
1.
nasm -felf64 -o my_write.o my_write.s




gcc -o test main.c my_write.o




/usr/bin/ld: my_write.o: warning: relocation against `__errno_location@@GLIBC_2.2.5' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: my_write.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `__errno_location@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

give me a this error.

Also note that errno is 32 bits only so don't write 64 bits into it. Furthermore, as Peter commented on the question where you probably took the code from without attribution, rdi is not preserved across calls so that won't work.

You need to use a PIE-compatible call in your asm code:
call __errno_location@PLT

in general, for PIE, when calling a symbol that will be provided in a different .so, you need @PLT

When foo is a function in a shared library, your options are:

call *foo@GOTPCREL(%rip)  like gcc -fno-plt would do, a memory-indirect call that loads a new RIP from the Global Offset Table entry which is addressed with a RIP-relative addressing mode.
The is usually the most efficient, and how modern Linux distros compile their packages.  This results in early binding, resolving the symbol and filling in the GOT entry when the dynamic linker first runs before your program's _start.
GAS .intel_syntax noprefix version: call [foo@GOTPCREL + rip]

call foo@plt to have the linker invent a PLT stub which uses the GOT entry.
This is a direct call rel32; the PLT entry contains a jmp *rel32(%rip).
This allows lazy binding, with the first call to the function calling into the dynamic linker's code.  So it's good for functions that are never called in normal runs of a program.

Link as a non-PIE with gcc -fno-pie -no-pie.  In a non-PIE, ld will rewrite call foo to call foo@plt for you when the definition is found in a shared library instead of static.  Not an option for some projects, including if you're making a shared library that calls into other shared libraries.



A NASM version of the same question Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code discusses some of the differences and shows an example of a linker relaxing call foo@GOTPCREL(%rip) to directly calling foo when a definition is found in the .o files you pass to ld, not just in a shared library.
NASM uses different than GAS's @.


the compiler tells me to recompile using the -fPIE option. But when I do it again it gives the same error message.

-fPIE is a code-gen option which affects C to asm.  This error message was written for the use-case where you compiled C to a .o with gcc -c and then try to link it into a shared library or PIE executable.  (Especially in the days before most distros configured GCC to have -fPIE as the default).
-fPIE doesn't do anything for hand-written assembly code.  You are the "compiler", and need to write PIE-compatible assembly.  See also 32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?

Re: your specific code:  as @Jester points out:
errno is 32 bits only so don't write 64-bit RAX into it. And

Furthermore, as Peter commented on the question where you probably took the code from without attribution, rdi is not preserved across calls so that won't work.

Save the errno value in stack memory across the call.  (Or save/restore rbx and copy it to ebx)

Oops, this question is using NASM to assemble the .s.  I was fooled by the lack of a [nasm] tag, and Chris's answer suggesting call __errno_location@PLT which only works with GAS, not NASM.  Maybe I should write a self-answered Q&A about GAS where I can post this...  This question is a duplicate of the NASM/YASM one I linked in this answer.

Thanks for your answer. This info 32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux? very useful. I'm new to this, so I have to say that I'm superficial. Also, this type of informations are not very common.
